# How do $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\tan(n)}{2^n} =0 $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How do one show $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\tan(n)}{2^n}=0 $

But, I didn't compute $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\tan(n)}{2^n} $, as $\lim_{n\to\infty} \tan(n) $ doesn't exist even in extended real line. So, I am unable to use L'Hospital's rule.

What should I do?

My other question is what is the limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty} |\tan(n)| $, is it $\infty$ or doesn't exist infinitely?

Sorry to everyone for edit, i am now curious about this limit. That's why I edit it.

I knew, I asked a different question before in this post, but please don't do vote for closing it, I didn't know much about this $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\tan(n)}{2^n}$ because of the **tan(n)** term, so , please help me how should I deal with it?

Comment: It is better to ask two questions in two different posts

Comment: Yeah, but it is appeared in my mind with this question,, whenever I thought it through the absolute convergence case.

Comment: For b), the limit doesn't exist, as, roughly speaking, the function revisits each point infinite number of times

Comment: @Alex can you show it with sequentially?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: @Alex I mean can you show $\lim_{n\to\infty} |\tan(n)| $ doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, you use $n$ rather than $x$, do you mean you need a proof for the sequence, not a function?

Comment: @Martin R thanks for this link!!

Comment: As, I see $\sum \frac{\tan(n)}{2^n}$ is convergent, that means by necessary condition, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\tan(n)}{2^n}=0 $ but how can it be?

Comment: @Alearner: As you can see from the answer to the question that I linked to, this is not trivial and not simple. It is related to the “irrationality measure” of $\pi$. – See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2234996/42969.

Comment: @Martin R can this , $\tan(n)$ is dense in $(-\infty,\infty)$ , help ?

Comment: @Alearner: Sure, but how would you prove that?  I strongly assume that you would need the irrationality measure of $\pi$ again.

Answer (score -1):

For b), if the sequence diverged, then $\forall L>0 \ \ \exists n_0$ s.t.$ \tan(n)>L \ \forall n>n_0$. Yet $\tan (\pi k)=0 \ \forall k=2n, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence the sequence doesn't diverge. Use the same logic to show sequence doesn't converge either. Hence the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: The initial version about the question was about the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\tan(n)}{2^n}$. Therefore I assume that the current question is if $\tan(n)$ is bounded or not *for integer arguments.* The fact that $\tan(\pi k) = 0$ does not help here.

Comment: Yeah you're right this is the solution for $\tan x$